# Используется ли сейчас vector или только stack?

Tags: java, vector, коллекции, стек

И если используется то часто ли?
P.S. Зачем использовать Vector если есть Stack?

Comment: Конечно используется. Там где он нужен. А где не нужен - другие подходящие структуры данных (почитайте какие они бывают и для чего подходят)

Comment: не нужно их использовать, есть аналоги лучше в стандартной библиотеке. Кстати в 9 версии vector и stack планируется задиприкейтить http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы класса `Vector` синхронизированы, а `ArrayList` - нет. Соответственно методы `ArrayList` выполняются быстрее, чем потокобезопасные методы `Vector`.

Также имеются некоторые различия в реализации самой коллекции. Например масштабирование вверх `ArrayList` производится на половину размера текущей коллекции, а 'Vector' увеличивается в два раза.

Так что иногда `Vector` вполне можно использовать, если вам требуется коллекция с индивидуально синхронизированными методами. Со `Stack` все примерно также.

**UPD:** Вопрос изменился. Отвечаю:

`Stack` расширяет класс `Vector`. В `Stack` реализованы методы empty, peek, push, pop, search. То есть типичные операции со стеком.

Конечно он сохраняет в себе все методы `Vector`, но говорить, что `Vector` не нужен, раз есть `Stack` я бы не стал. `Stack` сделан для удобства. Можно использовать вместо `Vector` `Stack`, но лучше называть вещи своими именами. Вы же не станете переменную которая хранит ссылку на объект класса `Boy` называть `myLittleGirl`?

Comment: я имел ввиду если есть stack то нужен ли вообще vector?

Comment: Для быстрой обертки в синхронизованный доступ существует семейство методов `Collections.synchronized*`, которое нивелирует значение этой разницы

Comment: @антонсорокин изменил ответ.